# Short-circuit operations and empty matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, logical-operators

I have a question of short-circuit operations and empty matrices in Matlab. I put the short-circuit operations in my if statement. But sometimes I have empty matrices and hence they cannot be convertible to logical scalar values.

I've read this document. 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/empty-matrices-scalars-and-vectors.html
But I can't control the order of empty matrices and logical value.

In my mind I want something like "[] || 1 to be 1".

Thank you for your helping!

Here is the original code. This is a code for evolving voter model in network analysis.

```
clear 
clc
load('karate.mat');


rng shuffle
n = length(A);
rho = 0.5;
alpha = 0.2; %rewiring probability
%rewire to the same

t = 1;



B{t} = A; %temperal network
D{t} = zeros(n,n); % the discordant edges
S = zeros(n,1); % the infected nodes (set to zero if not infected)
SS = rand(n,1);
S(SS<rho) = 1;




for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        if abs(S(i)-S(j)) > 0.5
            if  B{t}(i,j) == 1
                D{t}(i,j) = 1; 
            end
        end
    end
end



flag=1;
t=1;   
while(flag)
    t=t+1;
    for i=1:n
        for j=1:n
            if(D{t-1}(i,j)>0.1)
                ii=i;
                jj=j;

                neighB=find(B{t-1}(ii,:));
                neighB1=neighB(S(neighB)==1);
                neighB0=neighB(S(neighB)==0);
                kB=length(neighB);
                kB1=length(neighB1);
                kB0=kB-kB1;

                neighD=find(D{t-1}(ii,:));
                neighD1=neighD(S(neighD)==1);
                neighD0=neighD(S(neighD)==0);
                kD=length(neighD);
                kD1=length(neighD1);
                kD0=kD-kD1; 

                if S(ii)==1     
                    if(rand(1)<1-alpha) %adopting
                        S(ii)=0;
                        if(kD1>0)
                            D{t}(ii,neighD1)=1;
                            D{t}(neighD1,ii)=1;
                        end
                        if(kD0>0)
                            D{t}(ii,neighD0)=0;
                            D{t}(neighD0,ii)=0;
                        end

                    elseif((max(S(find((B{t-1}(ii,1:(ii-1)))==0)))==1) || (max(S(find((B{t-1}(ii,(ii+1):end))==0)))==1)) %rewire could happen if there exists a node having the same status and is not a neighbor
                        B{t}(ii,jj)=0;
                        % have a problem to compare [] and 1 here
                        % Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.    
                        F=find(S(find((B{t-1}(ii,1:(ii-1)))==0)))==1 && find(S((find(B{t-1}(ii,(ii+1):end))==0)))==1; %not sure here
                        C=randperm(length(F)); %not sure here
                        B{t}(ii,S((C(1))))=1; %not sure here

                        D{t}(ii,neighD1)=0;
                        D{t}(neighD1,ii)=0; 
                        D{t}(ii,neighD0)=1;
                        D{t}(neighD0,ii)=1;

                    else
                        S(ii)=0; %if cant find other nodes to rewire, then change the status     
                        D{t}(ii,neighD0)=0;
                        D{t}(neighD0,ii)=0;
                        D{t}(ii,neighD1)=1;
                        D{t}(neighD1,ii)=1;

                    end        
                end

                if S(ii)==0
                    if(rand(1)<1-alpha)
                        S(ii)=1;
                        if(kD1>0)
                            D{t}(ii,neighD1)=0;
                            D{t}(neighD1,ii)=0;
                        end
                    if(kD0>0)
                        D{t}(ii,neighD0)=1;
                        D{t}(neighD0,ii)=1;
                    end

                    elseif((min(S(find(B{t-1}(ii,1:(ii-1)))==0))==0) || (min(S(find(B{t-1}(ii,(ii+1):end))==0))==0)) %rewire could happen if there exists a node having the same status and is not a neighbor
                        B{t}(ii,jj)=0;

                        F=find(S(find(B{t-1}(ii,1:(ii-1)))==0))==0 && find(S(find(B{t-1}(ii,(ii+1):end))==0))==0; %not sure here
                        C=randperm(length(F)); %not sure here
                        B{t}(ii,S((C(1))))=1; %not sure here


                        D{t}(ii,neighD0)=0;
                        D{t}(neighD0,ii)=0;
                        D{t}(ii,neighD1)=1;
                        D{t}(neighD1,ii)=1;     

                    else
                        S(ii)=1; %if cant find other nodes to rewire, then change the status
                        D{t}(ii,neighD0)=1;
                        D{t}(neighD0,ii)=1;
                        D{t}(ii,neighD1)=0;
                        D{t}(neighD1,ii)=0; 
                    end
                end
            end
        end

    end
    if(nnz(D{t})==0)
        flag=0;
        disp(t);
    end
end
nnz(S)/length(A)
disp(t)
```

Comment: Use [`isempty`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html). Something like - `isempty(..) || 1`

Comment: Thank you, but sometimes my [] part could have 0 or 1. So I don't know how to deal with that. All I want is if the result is not true(1), then it is false. No matter it is 0 or [].

Comment: What exactly is "[] part"? I am assuming you are running this on some vector or matrix or some scalar? So maybe take some example and show the desired output?

Comment: (max(S(find((B(i,1:(i-1)))==0)))==1 and (max(S(find((B(i,(i+1):end))==0)))==1)

Comment: Thank you Divakar, it's something I want to check as above. And I'm looping the i there.

Comment: Could you give the `whos` info on `S`, `B`? I am asumming `i` to be an iterator? Why not edit your question with these additional details? Also if possible, add the code that generates all these?

Comment: Sure, I'll put the whole details soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you create your own function that behaves how you want. For example, if you want the following behavior:

1. if matrix is empty, set value to true
2. if matrix is not empty, set value to "any" of the values
3. evaluate the OR of all arguments

Then you write a function:

```
function r = anytrue(varargin)
r = false;
for ii=1:numel(varargin)
  if isempty(varargin{ii})
    r = true;
    return
  end
  if varargin{ii}
    r = true;
    return
  end
end
```

Note that this exhibits short-circuiting behavior; you can obviously modify to fit whatever conditions you want to impose.